# $\int_{\alpha} \frac{1}{z}dz$ with $\alpha$ being the square $1,i,-1,-i$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm reading Freitag/Busam "Complex Analysis" (German edition). Exercise 1 in II.1 asks for the integral of $\frac{1}{z}$ along the closed square $1,i,-1,-i$. Like in the solution given I used the parametrisation $$\alpha(t)=i^k+(i^{k+1}-i^k)(t-k),\quad k\leq t\leq k+1,\quad k=0,1,2,3\quad(*)$$
I know this must be $2\pi i$. However, I get $0$ because if I integrate the four sides separately before summing $$\sum_{k=0}^3\left(\log\left(i^k+(i^{k+1}-i^k)(t-k)\right) \bigg|_{k}^{k+1}\right)$$ all the values cancel each other. I think I understand why that happens. So I was curious how they did it. They said: The integral is computed like this $$\sum_{k=0}^3\int_k^{k+1}\frac{i-1}{1+(i-1)(t-k)}dt=4i\int_0^1\frac2{(2t-1)^2+1}dt=2\pi i$$But how on earth do they get from $(*)$ to the left side of this equation? Why is the integrand suddenly the same for all four sides (apart from the remaining $k$ of course)? I also don't see how to get from there to the middle part. Where does the square come from?

Comment: Since it might not be completely clear from reading Martin's answer: the left and the middle part of the last equation are equal because the real part of the left side integrates to zero. The (modified) integrands $\frac{i-1}{1+(i-1)t}$ and $\frac{2i}{(2t-1)^2+1}$ are not equal! This is what threw me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral over the $k$-th side of the square is
$$
 \int \frac{1}{z} \, dz = \int_k^{k+1} \frac{\alpha'(t)}{\alpha(t)} \, dt
= \int_k^{k+1} \frac{i^{k+1}-i^k}{i^k+(i^{k+1}-i^k)(t-k)} \, dt
$$
and cancelling the common factor $i^k$ in the fraction gives
$$
\int_k^{k+1} \frac{i-1}{1+(i-1)(t-k)} \, dt
= \int_0^1 \frac{i-1}{1+(i-1)t} \, dt
$$
so that the total integral is
$$
\int_\alpha \frac{1}{z} \, dz = 4 \int_0^1 \frac{i-1}{1+(i-1)t} \, dt \, .
$$
The next step is to make the denominator of the integrand real by multiplying both numerator and denominator with the complex conjugate of the denominator, that gives
$$
\frac{i-1}{1+(i-1)t} = \frac{(2t-1) + i}{2t^2-2t+1} \, .
$$
Now you can compute the real and imaginary part of that integral.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen the possible cancellation of $i^k$. And I always made an error when trying to expand the fraction in the next step.